# twitter bootstrap input click outside of dropdown-menu; is hiding menu

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a form contained in a dropdown-menu which is displayed when the Advanced option is clicked, but when I click on the search input which is not contained within the dropdown-menu; the dropdown-menu closes.
I need the menu to remain visible when the search input box is clicked or focused.
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your code too?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) event to avoid closing of the dropdown menu.

```
$(function () {
  $('.dropdown-menu').find('input[type="text"]').click(function (e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
     });
});
```

Here is one bootply example for you. http://bootply.com/63262 .

**NB** Please make sure that you research a bit before asking questions, and also please provide relevant codes that you have used.